# What is the purpose of Using "Ultimate Thread Group": need to know the practical usage

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can some one explain what is the purpose of [Ultimate Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup) considering it's practical usage. I am new to JMeter and as I've learned (please correct me if i am wrong), we use "Ultimate Thread Group" to time scheduling the ramp up/down time of multiple threads we create for a particular JMeter scenario script.

I feel this also can be done using [Stepping Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup) as well by having multiple threads attached to the same test plan. So i need to know exactly what is the significant usage of Ultimate Thread Group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it to simulate a peak of users (as the Dirac delta function)

Comment: Can you give me some references that might help to compare the usage of Ultimate Thread Groups? or gain some more knowledge on ultimate thread group usage?

Comment: Hi ShiyamTJ ! The Ultimate Thread Group allow you to have no linear or no stepping thread group. In their exemple [link] (http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup), you can see a kind of "chaotic" thread group. You can use it to simulate 2 or 3 peak of VU.